# How to convert an AJAX POST into a HTTP POST so that it is posted on a click?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, post

I have the following working code - this is an AJAX, hence it POSTs without a click. I learnt that HTTP POST required a click - how can I convert it into a HTTP POST with a mouse click enabled?

Second part of the code actually works with a click - but it downloads to a local computer than sending it to a server - perhaps there are some ideas taken from it, such as var link = document.getElementById("save")? See original app at http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html.

Update:
I am newbie and I got these ideas from this blog:  http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/ajax_page.html

> Ajax (Asynchronous Javascript And XML) is a technique (or, more correctly, a combination of techniques) for submitting server requests 'in the background' and returning information from the server to the user without the necessity of waiting for a page load. Ajax is actually a combination of several technologies working together to provide this capability. How does it work?
>   Instead of a user request being made of the server via, for example, a normal HTTP POST or GET request, such as would be made by submitting a form or clicking a hyperlink, an Ajax script makes a request of a server by using the Javascript XMLHTTPRequest object.

```
     Recorder.setupDownload = function(blob, filename){

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', './upload.php', true);
      xhr.onload = function(e) {};
      // Listen to the upload progress.
      var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
      xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
          progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
          progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback for unsupported browsers.
        }
      };

      xhr.send(blob);
    }
     ================html code fragment=======
    #save, #save img { height: 10vh; }
    #save { opacity: 0.25;}
    #save[download] { opacity: 1;}


    ==========works with a click ----------------
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
        var link = document.getElementById("save");
        link.href = url;
        link.download = filename || 'output.wav';
```

Comment: You've seriously misunderstood the entire concept. There is no "AJAX POST" that would be separate from HTTP POST, and mouse clicking is certainly not required for either AJAX or "normal" requests.

Comment: I got this idea from this blog: http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/ajax_page.html - I am really looking for a solution, if anyone could help.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you just trying tin undersand how a plain, old-fashioned form POSt works?  What is actually the problem  (i.e. you expect the code to do X, but it does Y instead)?

Comment: Mike, I have added a working link, which has the entire code. What I want is, instead the file being downloaded to local pc, I want it to go to server on the click - I managed able to do it but it does not wait for my click. Secondly the image does not brightenup as with the original app.

Answer (score 0):

The `Recorder.setupDownload` is a function, therefore you can tie to events in your user interface. In other words you can instruct JavaScript to execute the function when some particular thing happens on the page.

Using your "works with a click" example, you could tie the `Recorder.setupDownload` function to it's *click* event:

```
var link = document.getElementById("save");
link.onclick = Recorder.setupDownload(myblob, myfilename);
```

Replace `myblob` and `myfilename` with the appropriate variables in your script.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/d396chza/)

Comment: What is "onclick" - does it need to be defined too? Thanks

Comment: `onclick` is predefined with particular JavaScript objects. It's a way you can give JavaScript some instructions what to do when that element is clicked.

Comment: Also, Recorder.setupDownload = function(blob, filename){ } automatically runs. How do I stop it so it depends on the click?

Comment: Find in your code where `Recorder.setupDownload` is called to make it automatically run. I'd do a search for "setupDownload" in my code and look for something like `setupDownload(var1, var2)`. Is this a library of some sort?

Comment: Made the changes but still have two issues (pls note that I inserted the html code on the very top). (i) the "save" image brightens up - that is not happening (ii) as u recommended I found code where Recorder.setupDownload is called and inside that function, I inserted the two lines from your answer {var link .. and link.onclick ...}. Yet, the file is being posted to the server without a click. What didn't I do it correctly?

Comment: The original app is at http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html: There are two images. The mic get clicked twice to start and stop recording - I am wondering if that click is being picked by onclick? How can these be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the following will do based on @bloodyKnuckles reply (I am still waiting on brightening up the hard drive image - contributions are welcome):

```
    var link = document.getElementById("save");
    link.onclick = function () {
        Recorder.setupDownload(myblob, myfilename);
    };
```